# How to insert an information from a another file based on a condition between the two files?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, tidyverse

I have these files:

file_1

```
ID  L_meat  a_meat  b_meat  L_fat   a_fat   b_fat
1     21     21       21      22     22      22
2     23     23       23      24     24      24
```

file_2

```
Sample  L          a       b
21     37.34     16.53   14.72  
22     79.92     2.90    10.70  
23     37.49     15.57   14.16  
24     71.03     2.51    10.44
```

and I would like this final file:

```
ID  L_meat  a_meat  b_meat  L_fat   a_fat   b_fat
1    37.34   16.53   14.72   79.92   2.90   10.70
2    37.49   15.57   14.16   71.03   2.51   10.44
```

I tried something like this:

```
file_1$L_meat[file_2$Amostra == file_1$L_meat ] <- file_2$L
```

But I failed. Some suggestion?

Comment: Convert both data into long format, then merge, then reshape it back to wide format.

Comment: Looks like we don't need 1st file? Try this: `cbind(file_2[c(TRUE, FALSE), -1 ], file_2[c(FALSE, TRUE), -1 ])`

Answer (score 0):

You could join those data frames like this

```
file_1 %>% left_join(file_2 %>% rename(L_meat=Sample),by="L_meat")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Did not work. I got this error: `Error in rename(., L_meat = Sample) : unused argument (L_meat = Amostra)`

Answer (score 0):

So, I used this code:

```
file_1$L_meat <- file_2$L[match(file_1$L_meat, file_2$Sample)]
file_1$a_meat <- file_2$a[match(file_1$a_meat, file_2$Sample)]
file_1$b_meat <- file_2$b[match(file_1$b_meat, file_2$Sample)]
file_1$L_fat <- file_2$L[match(file_1$L_fat, file_2$Sample)]
file_1$a_fat <- file_2$a[match(file_1$a_fat, file_2$Sample)]
file_1$b_fat <- file_2$b[match(file_1$b_fat, file_2$Sample)]
```

and worked well.